# Turning Text file to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a text file that has following structure:

```
mom:2
dad:3
mom:4
dad:2
me:4
```

And I need to make a dictionary that would display each name only once, but adding the numeric values together. In this case it would look like this:

```
{dad':5, 'me':4, 'mom':6}
```

How I should approach this problem?
I've tried

```
d = {}
  try:
    file = open(file.txt, "r")
    for line in file:
      (a, b) = line.split(":")
      d[a] = float(b)
  except IOError:
    print()
```

but i haven't found a way to count up the values.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I can see what you want to achieve, but a dictionary does not seem to be the data structure you would want to use here, as a dictionary does not have an order.

Comment: Consider posting a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You do realize that the use of similar keys will overwrite values.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Yeah that is why I was hoping to find out if there's possibly an alternative way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:                                                        
    fp = f.readlines()              

t = [l.strip().split(':') for l in fp if l != '\n']                                                                                                                   
d = {}                                                                                 
for l in t:                                                                          
    d[l[0]] = d.setdefault(l[0], 0) + int(l[1])
```